# Can installing Ubuntu 12.10 on its own partition affect my Windows 7 partition?

Tags: 12.10, partitioning, windows-7

Here is the scenario

I have already downloaded the ubuntu 12.10 desktop 32bit on ubuntu site.

Now I want to put it in my 4gb flash drive using the universal installer.

Assuming i have a 100GB hard drive, I want to use 
30GB for Ubuntu. (Is 30GB OK for the Ubuntu partition or should I put a little higher, like 50GB?)

- So there will be 70GB partition of my windows7 home premium 64bit
- So 100gb= 30gb ubuntu + 70gb windows

I will use windows 7 disk management to cut off 30GB before installing. I'm not sure if using this disk partitioning method can totally cut the disk partitioning away from windows. (if theres another method to totally take away a disk partition please do recommend it) 'for me to sure that it will not affect the original OS.'

I'm actually very new to Ubuntu. So explain it detail by detail. The laptop that I will install Ubuntu in is not mine.

I will use this OS for our thesis project so please advise me.

I also have 'wubi.exe' but I'm not comfortable using it.

Comment: In any case **do a backup of all your data**. Just in case you mess things up.

Comment: This site explains in detail how to go about it. http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Disk Manager will free the space you want and this space will be completely free, unless you specifically tell it to create a partition. It and Ubuntu will remain happy were they are and will not interfere in Windows.

30GB is more than enough for Ubuntu (although considering your HD, cut 20GB).

If you are nervous about Ubuntu, Wubi works extremely well and with the added facility of "un-installing" Ubuntu in case of problems is just what you want. I'd recommend Wubi.

There is excellent documentation on installing Ubuntu **AND** Wubi is user-friendly for newbies. Go for Wubi and you don't need to cut anything at all.

This guide will be all you might need as it covers all general issues : 
[Guide to Wubi.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)

And Welcome to Ubuntu! Enjoy it!

Comment: can i use wubi as an offline installer?, i already had the .iso file of ubuntu 12.10, inside the iso is wubi.exe? for example: i will do a partition of, let say (E:30gb) then i will target E: in wubi so that E: will be the ubuntu then use the .iso file to install it in E: . and also what is 'ubuntu 12.10 quantal quetzal' ? is it a version of 12.10?

Comment: @user112438 Just copy Wubi.exe to desktop and run it. For some reason, Wubi.exe doesn't work from the CD. Wubi is designed for off-line installation. You can update system components later. Quantal Quetzal is the cade name for Ubuntu 12.10, like Precise Pangolin for 12.04. yes Ubuntu will be installed in E:. No need of cutting the drive and freeing any space. Ubuntu will be installed in `Ubuntu` folder in E:.

Answer (score 0):

Wubi is the best choice for you. I have tested Wubi for a year and system behaves well.

Windows files are accessible from Ubuntu in the `/host` folder. There is no need to mount-unmount. You can easily uninstall Ubuntu from windows control panel. Windows and Ubuntu start from Windows boot-loader.

But wubi is slightly slower because of the NTFS file system.

I have compared 12.04 wubi and 12.04 stand-alone on same type of netbook Asus eee PC r051bx (with AMD C-60 APU and 1GB of RAM). The performance is just a little better than a proper install of Ubuntu.

**However, if there is a problem in Windows and it does not boot, Ubuntu is very hard to recover.**