# Can I use WUBI as an offline installer for 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, wubi

Can I use WUBI as an offline installer?

I already had the .iso file of **ubuntu 12.10 - i386**, and inside the iso is `wubi.exe`.

For example: I will do a partition of, `E:30gb` then i will target `E:` in wubi so that it will be  Ubuntu then use the .iso file to install it on E:

My Computer:

- Acer Aspire 5750-6683
- i5-2450m processor

Is it fine to do a dual boot? Can I run  Windows 7 Home Premium OS, with the custom theme and boot screen, can that effect dual booting?

I just don't want to damage any of files or either any of OS

And if I can't boot any of the operating systems what should I do? Can I avoid doing a clean install if that ever happens?

Comment: Refer your [own question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/225046/can-installing-ubuntu-12-10-on-its-own-partition-affect-my-windows-7-partition/225053#comment278182_225053)

Answer (score 1):

The name ubuntu 12.10 is `quantal quetzal`. A name is associated with each version of ubuntu.

Yes you can do it offline.

Custom theme/ boot screen or anything inside windows 7 doesn't affect dual booting.

wubi runs from from windows.  It is nothing but a program which runs from boot time.

It creates a virtual disk. So as long as the virtual disk are present you can have your ubuntu back after reinstallation of windows.

If ubuntu doesn't boot remove from `add remove programs` and reinstall.

I highly recommend you to go through https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

Comment: hey thx ^^ also thx for the link ^^